# How to query this in Activerecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, subquery

I have a model (say Requirement), which has three foreign keys `model1_id, model2_id and model3_id`.
Other than these, I have a `value` attribute in the `Requirement` model.
In my `requirements table`, I have multiple values for a single combination of `model1_id, model2_id and model3_id`.

I want to get all the requirements i.e. `Requirement.all`, and there should be only a single result for every combination, where the single result is the one which was created recently.

How can I do that?

**UPDATE(to clarify the question):**

Think of it as `A Student has many subjects and give many tests for each subject and the value column is marks.`
I want to get the marks for the last test in a subject that the student has given.
Just the last recent test of a given subject.

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question?

Comment: So, you are trying to group the records? Do you want to calculate some kind of SUM, AVG, whatever of the value column?

Comment: If you could provide the activerecord models declarations for your example it would help a lot more understanding your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the @student loaded (and associations hooked up), then this should work (using Geography as a sample subject) :

> @student.subject.find_by_name("geography").tests.order("created_at
>   desc").limit(10).sum(:mark)